# Why $lookup requires $expr if I add pipeline and make a variable?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I’ve been trying to get data from collection without using $expr inside $match pipeline stage because it’s less performant and compared to simple $match

Here’s a piece of code I’ve been working on:

```
        from: 'messages',
        let: { "iId": "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ["$interactionId", '$$iId'] },
                  { $eq: ["$author.role", 'agent'] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "messages"
      }
    },
```

I am expecting to change this condition to simply this:

```
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'messages',
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              "interactionId": "$_id",
              "author.role": "agent"
            }
          },
        ],
        as: "messages"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your "secondly" paragraph is an entirely separate question and also probably needs more information to be answered anyway. Probably makes sense to remove it from this question about $lookup and $expr and move it to its own question (with more information, such as the full pipeline) and current output

Comment: because you need to access the variable within the pipeline and pipeline itself cannot directly access the input document fields [lookup-join-pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-join-pipeline)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be:

```js
...
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'messages',
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "interactionId",
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          "author.role": "agent"
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "messages"
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`pipeline` inside `$lookup` doesn't have any reference to parent collection data, it only has the reference to current data.
so you always have to use `let` variables to access any data from the parent